# How to extend a JS class in fable

Tags: f#, fable-f#

Given a class defined in an external JS library (let's call it Foo) then I'd like to extend in F#

```
type bar() = 
   inherits Foo
   ...
```

However I can' only find examples of how to integrate with functions

and

```
[<Import("Foo", from="my-module")>]
let Foo = JsNative
```

will of course not let me derive Bar from Foo. So how Do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Import` attribute can be used on a `type` declaration. e.g.

```
[<Import("Foo", from="my-module")>]
type Foo() =
    class
    end

type Bar() =
    inherit Foo()
```

You can then also include signatures for the members of the class. It's instructive to look at examples of imports like the Fable React declarations: https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-react/blob/master/src/Fable.React/Fable.Import.React.fs

Comment: Wouldn't you need to erase the type as well, as to not override the already defined type?

Comment: The Fable compiler will not emit code for things with the `Import` attribute, they're only used for type checking.